# creating a function with a pointer to a list of integers that multiplies every element in the list by the additional value passed in

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct int_node IntNode;
struct int_node {
    int val;
    IntNode *next; 
};

typedef struct int_list IntList;
struct int_list {
    IntNode *front; 
};

void multiply_by(IntList *list_ptr, int m);

int main(void) {
    IntList list = create_list();

    insert_back(&list, 10);
    insert_back(&list, 71);
    insert_back(&list, 9);
    
    print_list(&list);
    free_list(&list);

    insert_back(&list, 5);
 
    insert_back(&list, 6);
    insert_back(&list, 7);
    insert_back(&list, 8);

    free_list(&list);

    return 0;
}

void multiply_by(IntList *list_ptr, int m) {
    IntNode *current_node = list_ptr->front;
    
    //Need Help
    
}
```

Ok so im creating a function `multiply_by` that will take a pointer to a list of integers and an integer value as an additional argument. The function has to multiply every element in the list by the additional
value passed in. But I'm not sure if I use array[] to do this or how I should go about the multiplying all the elements? could anyone give me an example or suggestion? maybe examples?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? That code should apparently only be a linked list iteration and a multiplication. Which of those two things are you struggling with (and how have your attempts at solving them been unsuccesful)?

Comment: You don't need an array. You just need to iterate over the list and do `current_node->val *= m;`

Comment: Tip: since you declare `IntNode *front;` you should go ahead and add `*back` to preserve `O(1)` in-order insertion time at the end of the list, e.g. [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Answer (score 1):

You should just multiply the data in every node by the number passed as an argument:

```
void multiply_by(IntList *list_ptr, int m) {
    IntNode *current_node = list_ptr->front;
    
    while (current_node) {
        current_node->val *= m;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
}
```